# Can <aui:input> be used for double values?

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6

I have been driving myself crazy trying to use the AUI taglib to input fields for a service builder object.  I am using the Liferay MVC environment.  The field `downPayment` is defined as a `double` in `service.xml`.  Here is what I am trying in the JSP:

```
<aui:form action="<%=submitApplicationURL%>" inlineLabels="true">
<aui:model-context model="<%=CreditApp.class%>" bean="creditApp"></aui:model-context>

    <aui:fieldset>
            ...
        <aui:input name="downPayment" format="${currencyFormat}" value="${creditApp.downPayment}" ></aui:input> 
            ...
        <aui:button type="submit" />
    </aui:fieldset>
</aui:form>
```

Also, does anyone know where there is more documentation for the the liferay AUI taglib?  At this point I am thinking of switching to something more familiar such as portlet JSF and dropping the whole "liferay way" thing altogether.  Some expert guidance would be much appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are familiar with JSF, you could use Primefaces which is much more mature, extendable, user-adopted, straightforward and documented.

In my experience, AUI taglib is rather poorly documented. Your development will be a constant trial-and-error experience while you're trying to use a feature that is not explained in the 'proof-of-concept'-style tutorials, and your only hope will be finding someone else's post in a forum. Ironically, AUI, being a less straightforward Library, needs a complete Documentation a lot more than other component libraries.

Comment: I have been reading their official book, "Liferay In Action", which advocates the AUI approach rather heavily.  It is unfortunate that the actual programming situation is so bleak when sitting down to implement something.  Do you have an experience with the ServiceBuilder?  It seems nifty, but does it bite you in development as well?

Comment: Yes, I'm using ServiceBuilder, but to be honest I don't have experience with other Hybernate -like implementations, so I can't judge. There are some things that feel weird, like practically missing the foreign keys feature, or having to represent a great part of the schema logic on the Impl classes. Maybe you should start another thread on this, and get the opinions of more experienced developers